# Is there a way to express matematically that B is closer to A than C is to A?

Tags: logic

Is there a way to express mathematically that B is closer to A than C is to A?

Eg. 3 is closer to 1 than 4 is to 1
or  -1 is closer to 3 than 10 is to 3

Comment: $\lvert B-A\rvert < \lvert C-A\rvert$?

Comment: Yes, there is such way.

Comment: In order to ask the question, you already had to express the concept you were asking about.  Most mathematical concepts are expressed in natural language, e.g. English.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you accept the possibility that the distance could be the same:
$|A-B|\le |C-A|$ otherwise, $|A-B|\lt |C-A|$